# If I have a pointer pointing at a struct, how can I access one of its members?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

If I have struct for instance:

```
struct head {
   int s; 
   char x;
};
```

And I have pointer pointing to this struct, how can I access char x using this pointer?

Comment: With the `->` operator, usually... I suggest you double check your tutorial/book instead of expecting SO to provide one spontaneously.

Comment: [Here's a complete list of operators](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/104/fall06/burt/precedenceTable.html). Read on the `->` operator.

Comment: Arrow syntax. ```myStructPtr->myMember```. In future, maybe google or a book would be a good idea. You'll probably find a more comprehensive answer

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that you have :

```
struct head headNode;
struct *head headPtr = &headNode;
```

you can access `char x` with :

```
headPtr->x;
```